# Notation of expectation $\mathbb{E}_{x\,\sim\,p(x)}\left[f(x)\right]$

Tags: statistics, notation, machine-learning, expected-value

I want to study some topics in machine learning and the author often uses this notation $\mathbb{E}_{x\,\sim\,p(x)}\left[f(x)\right]$. I just wanted to check if this is the same as (for continuous variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$)

$$\mathbb{E}_{x\,\sim\,p(x)}\left[f(x)\right] = \int p(x)f(x)dx.$$

or if this has an additional meaning.

Comment: That means exactly what you’ve written, assuming that you have omitted the domain of integration (the support of $x$) deliberately.